# Need to break the line at some index and without breaking the word using c#

Tags: c#, string

I have a string as below

> innerString s="Clicking Log Out will clear our cookies and log you out of Stack Overflow on all devices";

I need to break the string and form this in a lines format,each line should contains 37 characters

Condition :

> 1) It should not break the word
>
> > E.g: Clicking Log Out will clear our coo 
> >     ies and log you out of Stack Overflow on al
> >     l devices

I tried using below code

```
                int appendCount = linkCount / 38;
                    if (innerString.Length > 37)
                    {
                        int startvalue = 38;

            if(innerstring[startvalue]==" ")
            {
                innerString = innerString.Insert(startvalue, System.Environment.NewLine).TrimEnd();
                    startvalue = startvalue + 38;


            }

            else
            {
            int i=innerstring.LastIndexOf(" ",startvalue);
            startvalue=i++;
                            innerString = innerString.Insert(startvalue, System.Environment.NewLine).TrimEnd();
            startvalue = startvalue + 38;
            }
```

Output should be like this without breaking any words in middle :

> Clicking Log Out will clear our cookies
>   and log you out of Stack Overflow on
>   all devices

Comment: 1. format your code, it hurts in the eyes. 2. What (exactly) goes wrong? What is the problem you see? 3. Did you use the debugger, set breakpoints, inspect variables?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Looks like you are removing the last word if it is cut up. is this intentional? Or do you still want to display cookies on it top line.

Comment: If I break the line   then it should not break the word at the end

Comment: Right ok, thats what I thought, but in the edit you made it has removed the word cookies so I just wanted to make sure before I try to post an answer. Thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added the whole thing in a while loop and it works:

```
string innerString = "Clicking Log Out will clear our cookies and log you out of Stack Overflow on all devices";
if (innerString.Length > 37)
{
    int startvalue = 38;
    while (startvalue < innerString.Length)
    {
        if (innerString[startvalue] == ' ')
        {
            innerString = innerString.Insert(startvalue, System.Environment.NewLine).TrimEnd();
            startvalue = startvalue + 38;
        }
        else
        {
            int i = innerString.LastIndexOf(" ", startvalue);
            startvalue = i++;
            innerString = innerString.Insert(startvalue, System.Environment.NewLine).TrimEnd();
            startvalue = startvalue + 38;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn, I came back to add the exact same answer but you beat me to it :)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you added a comment to a previous answer and asked about another string that it doesn't work with. I don't know why you removed it but I went back and looked at this and have come up with a nice short answer which should work for any sentence.

```
    public static string SplitByLength(string sentence, int length)
    {
        //Split the sentence up into individual words to add to a sentence
        var words = sentence.Split(' ');

        StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();

        //loop through every word
        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            //And add each one with a space at the end
            line.Append(word + " ");

            //If we have reached the end of a line or we have the last word
            if(line.Length >= length || word == words.Last())
            {
                //add the line to the results
                ret.AppendLine(line.ToString());
                //start new line
                line.Clear();
            }
        }

        return ret.ToString();
    }
```

The variables aren't well named but I tested it with a few samples and they all came out as expected. I have also used string builders as it is much more efficient when altering a string constantly.

Answer (score -1):

As you wanted to break line after some index (which you are aware) try below....
Here Enviornment.newline won't work
var x_test = stringexample.IndexOf("\n");

Comment: If I break the line   then it should not break the word at the end ,